# Object Selection options not showing in 2.8

Tags: interface

I am using Blender V2.8. I am a novice user. The options to Add, Subtract from selection which is supposed to be shown below the top bar are not visible on my interface. What am I missing?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your problem is not fixed yet, and you are using the latest version of blender (Version 2.82):

- If the header is missing like this
  [image]
  then just click on the arrow pointing down at the top-right of the viewport window to unhide it.
  [image]
  [image]
- The texts were replaced by icons as shown below:

  [image]

  [image]
- If the Header is missing and you can't find the arrow as shown
  [image]
  then right-click on one of the control buttons at the top of the viewport window to show a Options where you can find the "Header" options And activate the "Show Tool Settings" checkbox found as shown below.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this bar still exists? All these options are available on the <kbd>N</kbd> panel > *Tool* tab. You can also find them in the *Properties* panel > *Active Tool* panel (second tab from the top).

[image]